# Creating VB.net .dlls with limited access

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.net 2015 to create .dlls. My question is how do i create the .dll so that only One Class open to the outside world.  Right now i have several Classes that are used for Lists but the show up as option to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels) that explains Access Levels in VB.Net.  The class you want open to the outside world should be declared with the `Public` Modifier:

```
Public Class MyExposedClass

   Public Sub MyExposedMethod()
       MyNonExposedMethod()
   End Sub

   Private Sub MyNonExposedMethod()
       Dim objMyFriendlyClass As New MyFriendlyClass
       objMyFriendlyClass.MyFriendlyMethod()
   End Sub

End Class
```

Then if you want `MyExposedClass` to be able to call other classes in the same assembly you can use the `Friend` Modifier.  The `Private` Modifier is what should be used if you do not want the class to be exposed to any class other than the parent.

```
Friend Class MyFriendlyClass

   Friend Sub MyFriendlyMethod()
       Dim objPrivateClass As New MyPrivateClass
       MyNonExposedMethod(objPrivateClass)
   End Sub

   Private Sub MyNonExposedMethod(ByVal objPrivateClass As MyPrivateClass)
   End Sub

   'Can be called by MyFriendlyClass
   Private Class MyPrivateClass

   End Class

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks seems to work just fine.  I new it had to be something simple just never messed with creating .dlls before.